# How can I change the width of a Bootstrap 3 modal in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to support IE8.  The modal itself works fine, but my attempts to resize it (which work fine in Firefox) don't work in IE8.

I'm just adding a class (wide-modal in this example) to the modal-dialog div (the 2nd nested one in the Bootstrap structure) and applying a width via CSS, nothing fancy.

HTML:

```
       <div class="modal fade" id="modalTest" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog wide-modal">
              <div class="modal-content ">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Testing Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img src="content/Example-Infographic.jpg" width="100%" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide-modal {
    width: 60%;
}
```

I tried adding the class to the div above and below to no (positive) effect.  It works like a charm where it is in Firefox, just no effect at all in IE8.  I also tried with a px width, no difference.  I do have the respond.js library in place so in general IE8 is behaving other than this.

Answer (score 80):

In bootstrap 3 you need assign width not to `.modal` class but to `.modal-dialog`

```
#modalTest .modal-dialog
{
    width: 500px; /* your width */
}
```

Comment: Wow, how does this work? Overwrite? Is this a bootstrap thing? I used % to make it responsive

Comment: This is important. Use ".modal-dialog" for Bootstrap 3!

Comment: This is the most simplest way to do it. Should be marked as the answer.

Comment: i only wanted it large on larger screens, so used:@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  #modalTest .modal-dialog
{
  width: 45%;/* your width */
}
}

Answer (score 14):

I used a combination of CSS and jQuery, along with hints on this page, to create a fluid width and height using Bootstrap 3. I also tested this on IE8 on Win7, and it works great.

First, some CSS to handle the width and optional scrollbar for the content area

```
.modal.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
  width: 90%;
}
.modal-wide .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And then some jQuery to adjust the height of the content area if needed

```
$(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - 200;
  $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
```

Full write-up and code at
http://scottpdawson.com/development/creating-a-variable-width-modal-dialog-using-bootstrap-3/

Answer (score 10):

I know it is late but just found in [bs3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you can add `modal-lg` class to your modals

```
<!-- Large modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
  Large modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
     ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">
  Small modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
   <div class="modal-content">
     ...
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: best answear - only one that use BS3 built-in options, and the fastest one

Answer (score 4):

This will of course change the width for all of your modal windows, but it might give you a better idea on how this works.  I just changed my modal windows this way.

```
    .modal-body {
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px;
        min-width: 800px; /* SET THE WIDTH OF THE MODAL */
    }

    .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 6px;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        background-clip: padding-box;
        width: 900px; /* SET THE WIDTH OF THE MODAL */
        margin: 50px 0 0 -150px; /* CHANGE MARGINS TO ACCOMMODATE THE NEW WIDTH */
    }



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#modalTest.modal-dialog{
    width: <insert size> !important;
}
the !important is important :v
```

Comment: Or you can add a class to the body and make this : #class_body .modal-dialog { width: 60% ; }

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set the width in pixels and adjust the margin-left. For example,

```
.modal-dialog {
    width:700px;
    margin-left:-320px;
}
```

The margin left must be half the width of the modal, minus 30px for the scrollbar.

Here's an example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/85213