# Bootstrap: How can I change a modal's width with CSS without affecting other modals?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my application and it has a couple of modals. I want the modals to have different widths, but the only way I have found to change the width is to change the value of `modal-dialog` or `modal-content` in CSS. If I do this, it changes the width of the other modals as well. The examples I have found are usually for one modal which haven't helped much.

The modal is opened using:

```
this.$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'Modal.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl'}

           );
```

The modal is defined in an html file and I use CSS to style it.

Is there a way that I can have different modal widths without changing the value of `modal-dialog` or `modal-content`?

Comment: Why not use CSS for each specific modal?

Comment: use the `size` option. Very simple to extend the 2 optional sizes with simple css rule per size. I am assuming this is angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: I found another way of doing it by using the windowClass property. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by defining the "windowClass" property inside the $modal.open block. I found this other question and this worked without affecting the other modals: 
[How do I increase modal width in Angular UI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap)

This is what I used:

```
this.$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'Modal.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl',
                windowClass: 'my-modal'}
           );
```

Then I specified the width of the modal inside css:

```
.my-modal .modal-dialog
{
    width:300px;
}
```