# bootstrap ui modal size

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a modal:

```
controller.buildingDetailsPopup = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "/app/View/Partials/_biuldingDetailsPopup.html",
        controller: "biuldingDetailsPopupController",
        size: 'lg'

    });
```

is there a way to increase  more big width via property size?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap/21312755#21312755) post

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs):

> `size` (Type: `string`, Example: `lg`) - Optional suffix of modal window class. The value used is appended to the modal- class, i.e. a value of `sm` gives `modal-sm`.

Perhaps create your own CSS class and make it the size you want?

Comment: in size property has a larger class size ?

Comment: I don't see one [in the example](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/docs/demo.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would set the size option to my customOption(ex: mySize) and create a CSS class as below.

```
.modal-mySize {
   width: 1130px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can override the css class for modal.

Example:

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 35%;
}

    .modal-dialog .modal-lg {
        width: 60%;
    }
```