# Change the modal size in ng-bootstrap UI (angular 2)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the size of my ng-bootstrap modal, and I tried a lot of methods including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap) and [this](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1309) but nothing is working for me !, so can anyone give me some hints on how to control the width of the ng-bootstrap modal in **angular2**. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried CSS, prepending the rule :host /deep/ at the beginning of the CSS rule?

Comment: that didn't work too !

Comment: get bootstrap modal dialog class and then overerite it. you can user /deep/ before class name

Comment: First experiment within the browser dev tools (I suggest the Chrome browser). You can highlight the element directly and apply a CSS rule right within the dev tools (no need for :host /deep/ when using the dev tools). Once you find something that works, use that same rule in your component, prepending :host /deep/   We'd probably have to see sample code to help more.

Comment: Thanks, @KetanAkbari

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the default bootstrap css class `modal-lg` to my template:

```
<div id="modalId" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Body
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap default sizes:

- Small: modal-sm
- Large: modal-lg
- Extra large: modal-xl

Other options:

- Vertically centered: modal-dialog-centered
- Scrollable content: modal-dialog-scrollable