# Dynamic size bootstrap modal dialog in meteor

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have an app that I need to show images in (after clicking on a thumbnail), written in meteor.

I'm able to store the images in gridFS and pull them out fine, but am struggling to work out how to dynamically size a modal dialogue for showing the full size image.

I think I need to trap the bs-show event for the dialogue and set the .css.width property to the size required, but I have no idea how to intercept the bs-show event in meteor.

I have tried putting the following code in the app

```
Template.projectImageItem.events = {
    "click .open-modal" : function(e,t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Session.set("selectedImageId", t.data._id);
        Session.set("showProjModal", true);
        //console.log("Image ID: "+ Session.get("selectedImageId"));            
        console.log($("projectImageModalID").find('modal-body'));
    $("projectImageModalID").find('modal-body').css({
      width: '20px'
    });

    $("#projectImageModalID").modal("show");
    }
};
```

and in the chrome debugger can see the object being returned to the consol log, but the css change has no effect before the show so I guess I'm not in the right place for this.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be meteor specific. If you're using bootstrap  have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346203/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-bootstrap-3-modal-in-ie8

Comment: That is the technique I'm attempting to use. The bit I'm unclear about is how to intercept the $('#modal').on('show', in meteor.